# AMPscript / ExactTarget: date format

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I use `%%=Format(@datestart, "MMMM d, yyyy")=%%` to display the date in a specific format. 
However it doesn't display corectly in some cases. E.g.:
 16/04/2016 from my file remains the same while 01/08/2016 display somewhat correctly with the day/month reverted January 8, 2016.
The ET documentation doesn't give me what I need in this case, any idea how to fix? I also tried `%%=Format(@datestart, "MMMM dd, yyyy")=%%` and this `%%=Format(@datestart, "MM d, yyyy")=%%`. Nothing really works. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are the dates from your file inconsistent in format?

Comment: they aren't. Try to paste April 16, 2016 and August 1, 2016 into your CSV data file and they will become 16/04/2016 and 01/08/2016.

Comment: What's the data type of your data extension column?

Comment: you were right. However I changed to Date and now it gives me error when I try to upload the CSV: Invalid value: 16/04/2016.

Comment: I'd suggest importing into a staging table and having a query activity transform the text dates to actual dates into another data extension.

Comment: I solved it. I changed the format of the date columns in the CSV file to Date and then selecting the second option (*March-14-01) then I reverted back to text instead of Date for the data extension. I reimported and now the date is all good. The last thing I did is changing the call to %%=FormatDate(@datestart, "MMMMMMMMMM DD, YYYY")=%% - the month name was trimmed before to only 3 letters. Done! And, yes FormatDate works better it seems.